# unable split string java with regex

Tags: java

I tried below code with regex also unable to get expected output:

```
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String cmd1 = "x509 load 2 -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEILl8VJJBDym8m0IL+ksKwCSNGg+fW6VELvozl2lIZx6g\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
        String cmd2 = "x509 load 3 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\\nMC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEILl8VJJBDym8m0IL+ksKwCSNGg+fW6VELvozl2lIZx6g\\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
        List<String> listcmd1 = Arrays.asList(cmd1.split(" "));
        List<String> listcmd2 = Arrays.asList(cmd2.split(" "));
        System.out.println(listcmd1);
        System.out.println(listcmd2);

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[x509, load, 2, -----BEGIN, PRIVATE, KEY-----\nMC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEILl8VJJBDym8m0IL+ksKwCSNGg+fW6VELvozl2lIZx6g\n-----END, PRIVATE, KEY-----]
[x509, load, 3, -----BEGIN, CERTIFICATE-----\nMC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEILl8VJJBDym8m0IL+ksKwCSNGg+fW6VELvozl2lIZx6g\n-----END, CERTIFICATE-----]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[x509, load, 2, -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEILl8VJJBDym8m0IL+ksKwCSNGg+fW6VELvozl2lIZx6g\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----]
[x509, load, 3, -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEILl8VJJBDym8m0IL+ksKwCSNGg+fW6VELvozl2lIZx6g\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----]
```

Comment: Well, your regex is just a literal space, and it has split your string by spaces, as should be expected.  What do you want it to do differently?  Why do you expect it to give your expected output?  We're going to need more information in order to help you in a meaningful way.

Comment: You should replace Expected with Required in your question, because `split` works as expected! Your problem can only be solved with `split` if you eliminate the spaces in `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` and `BEGIN CERTIFICATE`. Remove or replace them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `limit` argument to [split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)):

```
    String cmd1 = "x509 load 2 -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEILl8VJJBDym8m0IL+ksKwCSNGg+fW6VELvozl2lIZx6g\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    String cmd2 = "x509 load 3 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\\nMC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEILl8VJJBDym8m0IL+ksKwCSNGg+fW6VELvozl2lIZx6g\\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
    List<String> listcmd1 = Arrays.asList(cmd1.split(" ", 4));
    List<String> listcmd2 = Arrays.asList(cmd2.split(" ", 4));
```

That way, the 4th and final element will contain your whole key.

Answer (score 1):

That's because there are spaces here: `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and here `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

You need to either:

**A)** Change `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` to `-----BEGIN-PRIVATE-KEY-----` and `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` to `-----BEGIN-CERTIFICATE-----`

or if you *really* don't want any hyphens...

**B)** You can join the indexes 3, 4 and 5 of the arrays for the **PRIVATE-KEY** and 3 and 4 for the **CERTIFICATE** (NOT RECCOMENEDED, but works)

```
listcmd1.set(3,listcmd1.get(3)+" "+listcmd1.get(4)+" "+listcmd1.get(5));
listcmd1.remove(4);
listcmd1.remove(5);

listcmd2.set(3,listcmd1.get(3)+" "+listcmd1.get(4));
listcmd2.remove(4);
```